# How to group an array like this

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, group-by

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lvid] => 01-3234
            [status] => 0
            [totals] => 500
            [tgls] => 2020-05-24
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [lvid] => 01-3234
            [status] => 1
            [totals] => 100,100
            [tgls] => 2020-05-24,2020-05-25
        )    
)
```

and i hope the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [01-3234] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [2020-05-24] => 500
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [2020-05-24] => 100
                            [2020-05-25] => 100
                        )
                )             
        )
)
```

anybody help me,pls

Comment: Do you have any code you wrote to do this? How can we help you without bringing something you started to write down?

Comment: first array is result of query and i want to make new array from first array to be like second array.

Comment: Edit your question above, write down what code you wrote, what output you have, and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of <kbd>[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)</kbd> and <kbd>[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)</kbd> functions

```
akshay@ideapad:~$ cat test.php 
<?php

$input = array(
        array( "lvid" => "01-3234", "status" => 0, "totals" => 500, "tgls" => "2020-05-24" ),
        array( "lvid" => "01-3234", "status" => 1, "totals" => "100,100", "tgls" => "2020-05-24,2020-05-25"  )
);

// your given input samples
print_r($input);

// process and create new array
$out=array();
foreach($input as $item)
{
    $toadd = array_combine(
                explode(",",$item["tgls"]),
                explode(",", $item["totals"])
             );

    if(isset($out[$item['lvid']]))
    {
           $out[$item['lvid']][] = $toadd;            
    }else
    { 
           $out[$item['lvid']] = array($toadd);
    } 
}

// finally expected output
print_r(array($out));
```

**Tested on:**

```
akshay@ideapad:~$ php --version
PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:02:44) ( NTS )
```

**Output:**

```
akshay@ideapad:~$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lvid] => 01-3234
            [status] => 0
            [totals] => 500
            [tgls] => 2020-05-24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lvid] => 01-3234
            [status] => 1
            [totals] => 100,100
            [tgls] => 2020-05-24,2020-05-25
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [01-3234] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [2020-05-24] => 500
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [2020-05-24] => 100
                            [2020-05-25] => 100
                        )

                )

        )

)
```